# Connecting docker running nginx, laravel, php to local desktop ms sql server(express)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, docker, nginx

I need to connect my docker container to my local Window's desktop's ms sql server (express, if that matters).

What I've done:

- Added the following to my docker compose

  ```
  extra_hosts: 
        host.docker.internal:host-gateway
  ```
- Checked that I can now ping host.docker.internal from the terminal within docker (successful)
- Assigned a static port, opened it on Window's firewall, allowed external connections from the database manager
- Attempted to modify the laravel .env to include the path to the database, here is my database section of laravel env:

  ```
  DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
  DB_HOST=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS
  DB_PORT=49172
  DB_DATABASE=sail
  DB_USERNAME=sa
  DB_PASSWORD=Pass@word
  ```
- I uncommented the section of database.php requiring trusted connection:

  ```
       'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
       'sqlsrv' => [
         'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
         'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
         'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
         'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
         'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
         'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
         'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
         'charset' => 'utf8',
         'prefix' => '',
         'prefix_indexes' => true,
       // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
        'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
  ```
- I installed the sql server pdo files from my php.dockerfile:

  ```
       FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine
       ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      # Get repository and install wget and g++
       RUN apk add --no-cache wget
       RUN apk add --no-cache gnupg 
       RUN apk add --no-cache libxml2-dev 
       RUN apk add --no-cache unixodbc-dev
       # Install PHP extensions deps
       RUN apk add --no-cache g++ 
       RUN apk add --no-cache unixodbc-dev 
       RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-            aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.10.4.1-1_amd64.apk
       RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.apk
       RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.10.4.1-1_amd64.apk
       RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.apk
       WORKDIR /var/www/html
  ```

Any help would be really appreciated.Every connection attempt has failed.

I am attempting connection tests using a php file:

```
     <strong>Database Connected: </strong>
     <?php
     try {
       DB::connection()->getPDO();
       echo \DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo 'None';
      }
      ?>
```

It always returns none.

I did set the TCP/IP protocol->Enabled yes and then set the weird port. I tried on 1433, but was worried it was maybe being used by something else. Switched to this following advice from a docker forum.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77034772/edit) to include the full and complete error message(s) you're getting - as text, not screen shots?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Serever (version) Configuration Manager tool to see which protocols are enabled for your SQL Server Express instance and what TCP/IP ports it might have enabled and be listening on? In the default configuration it almost never listens on tcp/1433 and rarely even has the TCP/IP protocol enabled.

Comment: There are no errors, just a lack of database connection when I try to connect. 
"Database Connected: None"

Comment: You mustn't be using error checking then. I suggest you have a read through the [sqlsrv manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php). When `sqlsrv_connect(...)` returns `false` you should be invoking `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` to report the error(s) and abort.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to do that in laravel when it references connection parameters in env. You are on to something though, I can try that in a raw form and then limit to a Laravel problem or a php problem :) thanks